# How do you set the page size of TbExtendedGridView in YiiBooster module?

Tags: php, yii, yii-booster

Is there an option in TbExtendedGridView widget where you can set the items to be shown in each page? I currently have this setting

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView',array(
'id' => 'client-list',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'type' => array('striped', 'bordered', 'condensed'),
'template' => '{pager}{summary}{items}{pager}',
'pagerCssClass' => 'pagination',
'rowCssClass' => 'pagination',
'pager' => array(
    'header' => '',
    'hiddenPageCssClass' => 'disabled',
    'maxButtonCount' => 3,
    'cssFile' => false,
    // 'class' => 'pagination',
    'prevPageLabel' => '<i class="icon-chevron-left"></i>',
    'nextPageLabel' => '<i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>',
    'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
    'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
    'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'your_css_class'),
),
'columns'=>$gridColumns,
'responsiveTable' => true,
'enablePagination' => true,
));
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @ineersa for the answer. I've modified my model's search function from this:

```
public function search() {
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('first_name',$this->first_name,true);
    $criteria->compare('last_name',$this->last_name,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

to this:

```
public function search() {
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('first_name',$this->first_name,true);
    $criteria->compare('last_name',$this->last_name,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>20),
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about TbExtendedGridView, but i believe simple pagesize will do the job.
Add this to your `$model->search()` before return:

```
$dataProvider->setPagination(array('pageSize' => 10));
```

Comment: Geez, thanks man! I've been looking for this for the longest time!